# stripe sending amount is divided by 100 automatically

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new on stripe when I transfer the amount to the test user I don't know what happens but it transfers 50 when I transfer 5000 and 100 when I send 1000 here is my code

StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

```
        var transferOptions = new TransferCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = 5000,
            Currency = "usd",
            Destination = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        };

        var transferService = new TransferService();
        var transfer = transferService.Create(transferOptions);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send in integer cents, so if you want to send in $500.00, you need to use 50000 as the Amount.

https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal